# Image is not rendering in pdf format

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I created a report in *iReport 5.1.0* which is running properly. There is a image in report, which is displaying properly on *JasperReports Server*. But when i export that report in PDF format then its take lot of time to generate pdf. When i remove that image then report is properly export to pdf format. But when image is used then it is not exporting in pdf format it take lots of time.

The image expression is : `"http://14.139.222.82:8080//"+$P{imagePath}`
The value of parameter *imagePath* is `/isi/onlineAdmission/studentImage/579.png`

The jrxml code is:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Admit_Card" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="cd1f65f7-0b93-435f-b13e-f2fa9f8d8ae9">
        <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/samples/11"/>
        <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://14.139.222.82:9090/jasperserver/services/repository"/>
        <subDataset name="instructions" uuid="f92d8a7c-2ea1-445e-841e-1265b14fcf4d">
            <parameter name="online_add_sess_map_pk" class="java.lang.Long" isForPrompting="false">
                <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
            </parameter>
            <queryString>
                <![CDATA[SELECT * from online_admission_exam_admitcard_instruction where online_admission_session_map_pk=$P{online_add_sess_map_pk}]]>
            </queryString>
            <field name="online_admission_session_map_pk" class="java.math.BigInteger">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="instructions" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>

        </subDataset>
        <parameter name="user_registration_pk" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="online_add_sess_map_pk" class="java.lang.Long" isForPrompting="false"/>
        <parameter name="imagePath" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="signaturePath" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            ]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="pk" class="java.lang.Long">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>

        <field name="address" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="online_admission_exam_center_pk" class="java.lang.Long">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="cityName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="city_code" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="state_name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="exam_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="schedule_date" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="shift_name_time" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="email_id" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="email_id_alt" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>

        <group name="User_registration_pk" isStartNewPage="true">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$P{user_registration_pk}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
        <group name="pk" isStartNewPage="true">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{registration_no}]]></groupExpression>
            <groupHeader>
                <band/>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <detail>
            <band height="82" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="d9be73ee-0d2b-472e-88b0-b72f36a01b8f" x="0" y="62" width="555" height="20"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["ADMIT CARD FOR ADMISSION TEST"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="8996ef53-ae5c-4fe8-8a6f-8ddac24fe47f" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="42" width="555" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#999999"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Email : isiadmission@isical.ac.in"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="41c09054-2de0-41c5-8baf-9ebdd6621feb" x="361" y="0" width="194" height="42"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["203, Barrackpore Trunk Road,<br>Kolkata 700108, INDIA"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
            <band height="411">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="acf9a427-8ebd-476f-8d42-d66de547b6b4" positionType="Float" x="0" y="1" width="212" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Name and Address of the Candidate"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="4502b4b0-56d7-4e4a-96c8-47293770ecf3" positionType="Float" x="212" y="1" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Registration No."]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="7ba31cab-2dd4-48b9-a61b-6d50b3b2fa8f" positionType="Float" x="212" y="136" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{gender}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="a3e1e483-86a0-4d39-b9b1-06c1e550b2ed" positionType="Float" x="212" y="16" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{registration_no}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="90df81d1-a8ef-4bf7-b709-73af0458997e" positionType="Float" x="212" y="31" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Programme Applied"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="65e5c8e8-5cdb-485f-a80a-d7399323ed94" positionType="Float" x="212" y="61" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Category"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="3e7f29ca-d82d-4811-95a6-ed3a53e92415" positionType="Float" x="212" y="46" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{programme_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="6e01480b-8e85-4b94-be9c-c8ef565a8ba6" positionType="Float" x="212" y="91" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PH"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="767ae279-c9c2-4a69-9ca4-6686d9d41fdc" positionType="Float" x="212" y="76" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{seat_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="823eae73-e4ca-4515-9d27-6c532f21992b" positionType="Float" x="212" y="106" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{physical_disable}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="da4b62a6-b9ed-4cc0-9f47-9f801f087205" positionType="Float" x="212" y="121" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Sex"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="99a61280-b1f8-4fa4-aa3f-8847cb899fa0" positionType="Float" x="0" y="16" width="212" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{studentName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="a0fb17bf-8af4-4584-9440-1bf183486688" positionType="Float" x="0" y="151" width="86" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" TEST DATE"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="c5eb4ccd-fb77-40ad-968c-fd14ed80f888" positionType="Float" x="0" y="166" width="86" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Reporting Time"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="7da99bb4-ed79-4582-b1bd-092a8a9f1899" positionType="Float" x="0" y="181" width="86" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["City"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="02f8e046-209f-4df4-a08b-572f79548ae8" positionType="Float" x="0" y="196" width="86" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["City Code"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="2e3e3840-4d31-4600-ad6b-139976ae1313" positionType="Float" x="212" y="151" width="194" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["TEST VENUE"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="a34c1c2e-3bd8-4938-bcf5-ca3d273dff04" positionType="Float" x="212" y="166" width="194" height="45"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="778caed1-7e09-4269-bd93-83424087c13e" positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="211" width="555" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#999999"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="d0901557-729d-49e6-8a24-ef3b4feac126" positionType="Float" x="0" y="231" width="153" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" TEST SHIFT"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="664953e5-011c-4504-8182-24aff5d97b85" positionType="Float" x="153" y="231" width="154" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" TEST CODE"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement uuid="48036a48-9a2b-4dbe-9f1d-7915ea82d13a" positionType="Float" x="307" y="231" width="248" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["SIGNATURE OF STUDENT"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="07909c30-d773-40c4-a5b6-0cd52b2119bf" positionType="Float" x="307" y="246" width="248" height="30"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[""]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="1ebd8879-f1f2-424c-8d0c-83ef8d6152f5" positionType="Float" x="423" y="321" width="132" height="14"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["(Dean of studies)"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="e931a4f5-3f4c-4df6-8cbd-40517d2698c5" positionType="Float" x="86" y="181" width="126" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cityName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="b855053a-00b0-41da-a571-c7bb77a57326" positionType="Float" x="86" y="196" width="126" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cpin_code}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="9ecb22ad-c3ae-4489-b15a-9b804c228b55" positionType="Float" x="0" y="46" width="212" height="105"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="html">
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{caddress1}+"<BR>"+$F{ccity_name}+"<BR>"+$F{cstate_name}+"<BR>"+$F{cpin_code}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="78bf4e67-8d10-4520-9414-16a6002acf7a" positionType="Float" x="86" y="166" width="126" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{reporting_time}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="bf671cd9-258c-484c-8035-c07986890fe5" positionType="Float" x="86" y="151" width="126" height="15"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{schedule_date}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="ba69b52c-8b35-4a40-8cdb-0b1b98d8f839" positionType="Float" x="0" y="246" width="153" height="30"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement markup="html"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{shift_name_time}.replace(",","<br>")]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="92711d97-2950-42d1-b941-788623cb3a6f" positionType="Float" x="153" y="246" width="154" height="30"/>
                    <box leftPadding="5">
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement markup="html"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{exam_name}.replace( ",", "<br>" )]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement uuid="c6d87f83-3e3e-4f47-9d69-2910409b7381" positionType="Float" x="406" y="1" width="149" height="210"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                    <image isUsingCache="true" isLazy="true" onErrorType="Icon" evaluationTime="Auto">
                        <reportElement uuid="86f1caad-1d22-4300-9c41-115d021d480d" x="17" y="14" width="100" height="121"/>
                        <imageExpression><![CDATA["http://14.139.222.82:8080//"+$P{imagePath}]]></imageExpression>
                    </image>
                </frame>
                <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="83988889-dfbd-456d-a4de-d517ef3e27cf" positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="341" width="555" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#999999"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["READ INSTRUCTIONS CAREFULLY"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <frame>
                    <reportElement uuid="6e128ef2-40dd-4c24-a5a9-586811a8beed" x="0" y="276" width="555" height="65"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    </box>
                </frame>
                <componentElement>
                    <reportElement uuid="ec5c4aab-6e98-4c88-9245-bcae9e946a30" positionType="Float" x="0" y="361" width="555" height="50"/>
                    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                        <datasetRun subDataset="instructions" uuid="dcf3c653-9b0f-474e-84e9-501c64bccf24">
                            <datasetParameter name="online_add_sess_map_pk">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{online_add_sess_map_pk}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                        <jr:listContents height="50" width="555">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement uuid="7eaf6ecf-2ab6-40af-8f02-089a738e7b14" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="50"/>
                                <box leftPadding="5">
                                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement markup="html"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{instructions}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:listContents>
                    </jr:list>
                </componentElement>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

The output on *JR Server* is:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the image by url from the same computer (with *iReport*)?

Comment: yes sir in the ireport i use the url in image ,it is display properly and in pdf preview image is also displaying.But in jasperserver it is not rendering in pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in the path, it should be
The image expression is : "http ://14.139.222 .82:8080 //"+$P{imagePath}
The value of parameter imagePath is isi/onlineAdmission/studentImage/579.png

Do check and let me know

Thanks